# Compare two ArrayList elements using method contains

Tags: java, arraylist

I am very new to Java

My claas is:

```
//Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
//(powered by FernFlower decompiler)

package linkedlearning.Mycucumbercourse;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RestaurantMenu {
public ArrayList<RestaurantMenuItem> MenuItems = new ArrayList<RestaurantMenuItem>();

 public RestaurantMenu() {
 }

 public boolean addMenuItem(RestaurantMenuItem newMenuItem) {
     if (DoesItemExist(newMenuItem)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate Item");
     }
         return MenuItems.add(newMenuItem);
 }

 public boolean DoesItemExist(RestaurantMenuItem newMenuItem) {
     boolean Exists = false;
    if (MenuItems.contains(newMenuItem)) {
         Exists = true;
     }
     return Exists;
 }
}
```

1. I populate array Menu Items of type of Restaurant Menu Item (class - see on the top) with an element which value ="Chicken sandwich".
   2. I pass to the method Does Item Exist (see above) an element of type of Restaurant Menu Item which value is also "Chicken sandwich".
   I would expect method **contains** to return value true.  However, the statement
   **if (Menu Items.contains(new Menu Item))** is evaluated as NOT true and the flow is going to the/ statement **return Exists;** meaning returned value is false.  /
   As far as I can see both Menu Items and new Menu Item contain "Chicken Sandwich" - see the screenshots of the debug below.

see the debug results for MenuItems:

[image]

see the debug results for newMenuItem:

[image]

The debug for Exists:

[image]

My question would be why method contains does not return value True.
Thank you in advance.

Hello, the class is:

```
package linkedlearning.Mycucumbercourse;
public class RestaurantMenuItem {
private String ItemName;
private String Descripotion;
private int Price;
    public RestaurantMenuItem(String itemName, String descripotion, int price) {
        super();
        ItemName = itemName;
        Descripotion = descripotion;
        Price = price;
    }

    public String getDescripotion() {
        return Descripotion;
    }
    public void setDescripotion(String descripotion) {
        Descripotion = descripotion;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        Price = price;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return ItemName;
}
```

Comment: please share your MenuItem class

Comment: Does your RestaurantMenuItem override equals method for ArrayList to compare?

Comment: Hello Digsb,   I have shared my class RestaurantMenuItem. 
@GiorgosDev , no it does not override equals method. Could you give me an example, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList internally uses 'equals' method in 'contains' method to identify if the object is inside the ArrayList. So in this case, you need to override 'equals' with the logic you need (may be, in your case, comparing value in Menu Item). That should resolve this issue.

Comment: `equals()` and `hashCode()` that is.